# Polar decomposition for general $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra，for each element $a \in A$ and $r \in (0,1)$，prove that there exists $u \in A$ such that $a=u(\sqrt{a^*a})^r$

I can prove it for normal elements. But how about the other elements？

Comment: If you have polar decomposition what stops you from letting $u= v\,|a|^{1-r}$ where $a=v\,|a|$ is the polar decomposition?

Comment: @s.harp: why would $u\in A$?